# Summing values in nested objects where key value pairs match

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem trying to sum values when they are within an object.

Given the following array:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "dick",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
];
```

I need to sum each of the numbers in the values object where the id matches,
giving the following result:

```
const result = [
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 20, twenty: 40, thirty: 60 },
  },
  {
    id: "dick",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 20, twenty: 40, thirty: 60 },
  }
];
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Maybe some combination of reduce and map?

Comment: What have you tried? You asked the identical same question yesterday and were directed to similar *"groupBy"*

Comment: You are actually on the right way. Reduce should do the job. Just create an acc with all the properties and check if the element is already in your array. create a new one, if not and add it to the existing one, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks - I'll post what I've tried shortly.  Building a new array and checking for existing seems promising - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the desired data. For this iterating over the object and looks if in the new accumulated (at start empty) result-object exists a property with this id. If not, create one and add the object there. Otherwise add to the object the value of each property of your values-object.

At last use [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the desired array out of the object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "dick",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
];

let res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(cur.id)) {
        acc[cur.id] = { id: cur.id, values: cur.values};
    } else {
        Object.entries(cur.values).forEach(([key,value]) => acc[cur.id].values[key] += value);
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or old-fashion but simple loops style

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "tom",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "dick",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
  {
    id: "harry",
    values: { ten: 10, twenty: 20, thirty: 30 },
  },
];

// New data
const newData = [];

// Loop
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const item = data[i];
  let push = true;
  for(let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) if(item.id === newData[i].id) {
    push = false;
    for(const key in newData[i].values) newData[i].values[key] += item.values[key];
  }
  if(push) newData.push(item);
}

// Log
console.log(newData)
```